# Can I Use GridView SelectedIndexChanged Instead of RadioButtonList SelectedIndexChanged?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, event-handling, radiobuttonlist

I have a few reasons that I need this to happen, but suffice it to say that when I use the event handler for the RadioButtonList the sender object returns as just the RadioButtonList, and I need more information from the GridView because that's how I can uniquely identify which record my RadioButtonList is tied to.

I added an "OnSelectedIndexChanged" property to my GridView but it doesn't fire/handle when I want it to.  I'm assuming this has something to do with the way the GridView is designed to work.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this or a better alternative?

I also thought about using a hidden field, but I can't add it to the RadioButtonList so it won't help unless it's global.  The problem with it being global is that I can't set the value uniquely to the record that has it's RadioButtonList being altered.

Clear as mud? Please ask if you need any clarification.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thought I would add an answer and explain how I solved my issue.

Since the scope was too narrow, I needed to add a custom field to the radiobuttonlist.  I just went ahead and added the following code:

```
MyRadioButtonList.Attributes.Add("NecessaryField")
```

I added this so that everytime a grid view row was databound this code would aldo execute, ensuring that every RadioButtonList had this field.

After that it's available for use.